# Django: How to return queryset where item attribute choice_set IS NOT empty?

Tags: python, django

**FILE models.py**

```
# Create your models here.
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('data published')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

**FILE views.py**

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Question, Choice
from django.utils import timezone

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Excludes any questions that aren't published yet.
        """
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())
```

**Create Question in database using python:**

```
from django.utils import timezone
from polls.models imoprt Question, Choice
q1 = Question.objects.create(pub_date=timezone.now(), question_text="1+1=?")
q1.choice_set.create(choice_text="A. 1")
q1.choice_set.create(choice_text="B. 2")
q2 = Question.objects.create(pub_date=timezone.now(), question_text="8+2=?")
```

In Function get_queryset, how to return queryset that question does have choices ? For example, Queryset INCLUDE q1(two choices), but EXCLUDE q2(without choice).

THX!

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the questions without choices by excluding against `choice=None`.

You could do,

```
def get_queryset(self):        
    return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).exclude(choice=None)
```

Either you could use, `exclude(choice=None)` or `exclude(choice__isnull=True)`.

Comment: what about the objects with choice count==2?

Comment: OP had asked for a way to exclude objects without choices. Read the question carefully please.

Comment: Queryset INCLUDE q1(two choices)

Comment: If you look closely, " **For example**, Queryset INCLUDE q1(two choices) ", you could see the part where I have highlighted as **bold**.

Comment: i think he didn't ask queryset for only question without choices. if so, your answer would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter using [isnull](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#isnull)

```
Question.objects.filter(choice_set__isnull=False)
```

Comment: No, i think this's WRONG.
It filter all item that without choices, exactly not what i want.  The answer of Fazil Zaid is nice, exlucde(choice__isnull=True)

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Count
Question.objects.exclude(choice__isnull=True).annotate(choice_count=Count('choice')).filter(choice_count=2)
```

Comment: oh, Fazil Zaid's answer is suffice. But your answer is also worth.  sorry for my ambiguity of description.  :|

Comment: "Django: How to return queryset where item attribute choice_set IS NOT empty?" is in the top-most of page(That is my question, below that is more detailed description). Also thanks your worthwhile answer. :)